Prusa Mk3S+ fails mesh bed leveling
I have a strange issue with Mesh Bed Leveling when starting prints with my Prusa Mk3S+. It appeared without any prior issues after not printing for 5 days, on my first print after the pause.
I can run OctoPrint's "Bed Visualizer" without an issue and it shows me expected bed level tolerances. Trying to start a print though, 3x3 mesh bed leveling fails at the central reference point every time and the firmware enforces Z-axis calibration, which doesn't help.
Before, I had the same issue on the 3rd reference point before a print and in OctoPrint's "Bed Visualizer", after which I ran the initial calibration wizard, making it work with "Bed Visualizer" but it still fails before a print and enforces Z-axis calibration after which it fails again.
I didn't find anything that seemed useful for solving that issue while researching it on the internet. Is this a known issue, or can someone with more experience please help me out with this?
I am running Prusas 3.14.0 firmware on the printer.
